# Access Token Or Alternative for Microservices For Resource Level Granular Checks

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, authorization

Hi I have following structure :

Client App (layer 1)
Business logic Services ( Layer 2)

Business Logic layer consists of many microservices . Access token can be created and passed from APP layer to business logic layer. Business logic layer could validate the access token and allow access to required operations.

But Scenario is : user A logged in can access Resource 1 but not Resource 2 ( here resource means Individual records in database ) . How would I manage this situation ? These checks to resource is quite expensive and ideally would be beneficial to be done once from a performance standpoint.

However, Should each of my business layer microservices cross check always if user can access resource each time they are invoked ? Or Should there be a separate access token created when user tries to open each resource and then  pass to business logic layer so that it can trust and allow?

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with db records, you dont use access tokens. You should somehow relate the user with the records they have access to. It could be by using the user-id in your resource-table or a different table to associate user-ids with resource-ids. Instead of user-id it could be a user-role, if this is how you decide who has access to what.

Then, after you make the association on db level, you can make the db-queries for the given (authenticated) id or role etc

Comment: In my use case the user access to records are determined by another service and I need to consider this as context to perform an edit on that record in my DB.  In monolith, this was managed as a session object so any further downstream calls could be handled with the session information.

Comment: this is not clear at all. i think you need to understand what you re trying to do. now u mention sessions and monoliths. are you just trying to pass the session down to the calls? cause from what i can imagine you dont hit any db directly apparently. if you want to pass the session around through rest requests you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820297/java-how-to-pass-session-id-for-rest-api-call-in-api-testing

Comment: So if i cannot maintain an association at a DB level due to the 2 different data stores how could i tackle this situation differently ? Today , i pull the data from data store 1 and persist in session before updating the records to data store 2. This way Yes my monolith is responsible to authorize . With microservices approach i am trying to simulate the behavior with Access Tokens ( By sort of adding each item unique identifier to the token ) when user tries to open each item. This way microservices can just trust token and push the data to the data store 2.

Comment: first of all, when u migrate, you dont have to copy the exact solution but use the new technology's properties, strengths etc. but if you want to stick with it, as i said before, you can use a session-id in rest requests. this way you use the same session-id to track and authenticate calls of a user A down to store 1 and then store 2

Comment: Any relevant advantages of using session Id and session store instead of storing the data in Token

Comment: i think tokens are more suitable for server2server communication while session are used more on webapps. but if you have a good reason to use one or the other, go for it. its your decision based on your detail

Comment: I do believe strongly that there should be a DB level relationship that can be used to validate the access to data than using tokens / Session id.  The approach with token and session id seems to be like the next best alternative that could be reached till we achieve DB level relationship.  I mean modifying a token to access each record doesn't look good but I am not sure at this stage how do i approach it without introducing a stateful session in between

Comment: Would it be appropriate to go the route of OpenPolicyAgent ( PDP ) mode for solving this similar authorization challenge

Answer (score 0):

If resource 1 and 2 are general classifications, then it's advisable to implement access control in the token.

For example, you can assign roles to users, or ownership to resources - these are known as access matrix columns and rows. Then, sign the token using cryptographic algorithms such as HMAC or ECDSA (public-key algos have higher overhead than symmetric key ones, this needs to be considered).

There's a lot of information on Information Security SE you can check those out. Recommended search keywords: access-control, role-based, token signature, message authentication code, hash.